# Sort "d.mm" and "dd.mm" dates in ascending order

Tags: algorithm, go

I have `var keys []string`. A key represents the day and month formatted as either `"D.MM"` or `"DD.MM"`.

For example :

`1.02 (1st of February) - 2.02 (2nd of February) - 1.03 (1st of March) - 3.02 (3rd of February) - 31.12 (31st of December)`

I need the keys to be sorted as follows:

`[ '1.02', '2.02', '3.02', '1.03', '31.12' ]`.

First the months, and then the days within the months.

I first tried to parse the string into a float64 number because I thought it would be easier to work with numbers (see the comments), but it seems it is worst.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why this specific choice? This doesn't look like a good idea, because  of the problem you encounter (among a lot of other issues).

Comment: Things would work a lot better if it was MM.DD - there's a reason people often store dates as YYYYMMDD

Comment: To be honest, the array of float64 is not from my choice, I have to work with this. If I had the choice, I would do it another way, sure.

Comment: also, with fixed bits IEEE-754 floating point number, your 1.02 will actually be stored as closest-approximation, like  1.019999980926513671875 .  I know all these comments don't solve your actual problem, but still... Find a way to *get out* of this terrible data representation would be the first step I'd take in order to work properly with sorting and everything else

Comment: @Joe : I could manage to get that format if needed

Comment: @Pac0 : I did not tell everything, at the beginning, I have it in string. I first decided to parse it in float64 because I thought it could be easier to sort. May I update the post and title ?

Comment: Yes, keep it as string looks better IMO, at least you will be able to manipulate it without the floating point accuracy problem . See next comment from Mr Lister for simple solution.

Comment: It's a string? Then just flip the parts before and after the dot, and sort as strings.

Comment: And sure, please go on with editing title/question to reflect the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Pac0 : Ok thanks, I did.

Comment: @MrLister : I do not understand what you mean..

Comment: @Elwyn Tranform the strings from "DD.MM" to "MMDD", and then convert them to integer and sort them, the natural order of integers will be your date ordering. You can also simply sort them as string, with the natural lexicographic order, but make sure you don't forget the leading 0 for month before 10

Comment: It may be an information that I forgot to add but I need the original format to remain the same, I mean, it is useful for me for the next steps. So if I convert to int, and change the format, I need to do the reverse operation after that.

Comment: @Pac0 : did you notice that the month is after the dot and the day is before ? Or maybe I still do not understand you..

Comment: Well, I don't know how your program is structured, but usually for a sort, one could create a comparator function that will try to tell if some element is greater than another element. Inside this comparator function, you can do the conversion job. This conversion is only for some temporary variables in the comparator function, your *actual data* should not be modified. Mbo has given an example of such a comparator function in pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks, understood now. Do not know why the downvotes, I find the question useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need a Go program. Check [this one](https://play.golang.org/p/wtrkqKPVqz9):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strings"
)

type ByDay struct { sort.StringSlice }
func (a ByDay) Less(i, j int) bool {
    dmi, dmj := strings.Split(a.StringSlice[i], "."), strings.Split(a.StringSlice[j], ".")
    return dmi[1] < dmj[1] || dmi[1] == dmj[1] && dmi[0] < dmj[0]
}

func main() {
    days := []string{"3.03", "3.02", "2.02", "3.01", "1.03", "1.02"}
    sort.Sort(ByDay{days})
    fmt.Println(days)
}
```

It prints `[3.01 1.02 2.02 3.02 1.03 3.03]`.

I doubt `ByDay` is the best name, you'd better give it a more descriptive one.

Comment: You made a mistake described in my answer. Check your code with additional date '11.02'

Comment: Thanks a lot, with the appropriate fix it is working

Answer (score 2):

You need to use comparator function (As far as I see - `go` provides [such possibility](https://gobyexample.com/sorting-by-functions)) that separates string into two parts, compares the second parts, in case of equality compares the first part.
To provide correct comparison of days, transform string values to integers or just add '0' in the beginning if string length is 1 (to make '21' > '7')

pseudocode:

```
 sort list with comparator func(a, b: string):
    a => lefta, righta
    b => leftb, rightb
    if righta > rightb
       return 1
    else if righta < rightb
       return -1
    else:       
      if length(lefta)=1
         lefta = '0' + lefta
      if length(leftb)=1
         leftb = '0' + leftb
      if lefta > leftb
         return 1
      else if lefta < leftb
         return -1
      else
         return 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will accept the Golang answer but yours is the correct algorithm with the prefix case

Answer (score 2):

For example, an efficient conversion and comparison,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func mmdd(key string) uint32 {
    // "d.mm" or "dd.mm"
    k := uint32(key[len(key)-1])<<16 +
        uint32(key[len(key)-2])<<24 +
        uint32(key[len(key)-4])<<0
    if len(key) >= 5 {
        k += uint32(key[len(key)-5]) << 8
    }
    return k
}

func main() {
    // 1.02 (1st of February); 2.02 (2nd of February); 1.03 (1st of March); 3.02 (3rd of February)
    keys := []string{"31.12", "01.01", "1.02", "2.02", "1.03", "3.02", "30.11"}
    fmt.Println(keys)
    sort.Slice(keys,
        func(i, j int) bool {
            return mmdd(keys[i]) < mmdd(keys[j])
        },
    )
    fmt.Println(keys)
}
```

Output:

```
[31.12 01.01 1.02 2.02 1.03 3.02 30.11]
[01.01 1.02 2.02 3.02 1.03 30.11 31.12]
```